# Adding up all doubles in a loop, Java

Tags: java

So I have to create this program that reads a number of 'salaries' from a file, then adds all the salaries up to return one 'total salary' and also calculates the average of all the salaries.

The code I currently have is below:

```
package uploadTask7_countingSalaries;

//import utilities needed for the program
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class countingSalaries {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        // defines the file that data will be read from
        File salaryFile = new File("salaries.txt");
        // creates scanner object to read data from file
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner (salaryFile);
        // creates while loop to read and print data to the user
        while(scanFile.hasNextDouble()) {
            double i = scanFile.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(i); }

        double addedSalary = scanFile.nextDouble();
        double sumofSalary = 0.0;
        while(scanFile.hasNextDouble()) {
            sumofSalary += addedSalary;
            addedSalary++; }

        System.out.println("Total salary is: " + addedSalary);

        }
    }
```

So far I've been able to read the salaries from the text file and print them out to the user. I'm struggling to find a way to add up all the numbers / calculate the average from the external file using a loop.

Comment: Why are you adding to `addedSalary`? It'll e overwritten. You need to have a separate `int` that stores how many salaries you collected, and then you can divide to have the average.

Comment: just add a counter that increments by 1 every time you add to sumofSalary. Also as a side note, why do you have multiple while loops for the file? you only need to read the file once.

Comment: You should be able to do this with 1 loop. Within that loop, keep a counter of number of salaries read and a running total of the sum of salaries. After reading all salaries, divide total sum by number of salaries.

Comment: I think you need one more variable than what you have here - something that counts how many salaries have been read.  You've tried to do this with `addedSalary++;`, but that's not a suitable variable to increment, since it hold an actual salary value, not a count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way. It seems you are trying to iterate twice without resetting the iterator.

```
package uploadTask7_countingSalaries;

//import utilities needed for the program
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class countingSalaries {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        List<Double> salaries = new ArrayList<Double>();
        // defines the file that data will be read from
        File salaryFile = new File("salaries.txt");
        // creates scanner object to read data from file
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner (salaryFile);
        // creates while loop to read and print data to the user
        while(scanFile.hasNextDouble()) {
            double i = scanFile.nextDouble();
            salaries.add(i);
            System.out.println(i); }

       double total = 0;
       for(double a : salaries){
        total = total + a;
       }

        System.out.println("Total salary is: " + total);
        System.out.println("Avg = " + total/salaries.size();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sum up the salaries after reading each of them in your while loop so after each read you'll have a partial sum. After you get the sum, you can calculate the average based on the total sum and the count of elements you've read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You need an additional int variable, that holds the number of salaries read , and then you can use this variable to calculate the average.

```
double addedSalary = scanFile.nextDouble();
            double sumofSalary = 0.0;
            int count = 0;
            while(scanFile.hasNextDouble()) {
                count ++;
                sumofSalary += addedSalary;
                addedSalary++; }
            double average = sumofSalary/ count;

            System.out.println("Total salary is: " + addedSalary);
```